# Roundtripping a std::list::iterator through void * with std::bit_cast

Tags: c++, c++23

Assuming `userdata` is never dereferenced, why is the following undefined behaviour?

```
std::list::iterator iter = [ ... ];
auto userdata = std::bit_cast<void *>(iter);
c_api_set_void_ptr(userdata);
auto iter = std::bit_cast<std::list::iterator>(c_api_get_void_ptr(userdata));
auto elem = *iter;
```

`bit_cast` checks the sizes and triviality, leaving the possibility of producing an invalid value of one of the types. Are there restrictions on values of `void *`? Does the situation change when limited to x86-64?

Comment: `std::list::iterator` is not a valid type. You mean something like `std::list<int>::iterator`.

Comment: Why do you think it's UB?

Comment: It is not generally UB, but can be depending on how the C++ implementation chooses the representation of both `void*` and `std::list<T>::iterator`. If you know that `void*` has no padding bits and all its object representations are distinct valid values, then, except that it may fail to compile, there is no problem.

Comment: Although, if you want to be languge-lawyery, there is a problem with what value the resulting `void*` could possibly have. It needs to be one of the possible categories of pointer values and only an _invalid pointer value_ really makes sense. The behavior of copying such an invalid pointer value would be implementation-defined and may not be allowed.

Comment: Iterators are not (guaranteed) to be pointers. What you probably mean is you want to pass a pointer to the data the iterator is refering to not the address of the iterator itself. In other words : for all you know the iterator itself is iterating internal node structs not data itself

Comment: If `c_api_set_void_ptr` and `c_api_get_void_ptr` don't hold on to the argument beyond their own execution, you can pass a pointer to the `iter` instead. All object pointers can be cast to `void*` and back without loss of data.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Then you need to deal with the lifetime of the iterator. Though if they don't need the iterator and simply the object, they can use `static_cast<void*>(std::addressof(*iter))` instead, since the object's lifetime is managed by the list

Comment: @Artyer That is why I specified *"If c_api_set_void_ptr and c_api_get_void_ptr don't hold on to the argument beyond their own execution"*.

Comment: Thinking about it a bit more, I suspect that if e.g. `std::list<T>::iterator` contains a pointer, then there is no guarantee that the second `bit_cast` will produce the same pointer value pointing to the same object as the original, because there are multiple such pointer values with the same object representation and `bit_cast` is specified to produce an unspecified one. The compiler may make assumptions about how pointers are derived while optimizing which I suspect may be violated by this.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming libstdc++/libc++/MSVC STL:

If any debug mode was enabled that made the list iterator hold more members, this would be ill-formed and fail to compile because the `sizeof(iterator)` would be too large.

Otherwise, in all three of these implementations, there is simply a pointer to an internal list node. On x86-64, all pointers have the same value representation and size, so this bit cast would be valid and produce a valid pointer (to the list node). Since there are no padding bits on an x86-64 `void*` pointer, no bits should be changed when this `void*` pointer is copied all over the place, giving you a `void*` pointer with the same value, which when `bit_cast` back gives you an equivalent iterator.

On a different standard library implementation, a `std::list<T>::iterator` might hold something besides a pointer that still has the same size. Or on a different platform the list node pointers might have a different layout than `void*` pointers. If the `bit_cast` does compile, an invalid pointer value might be produced.

Copying an invalid pointer has implementation defined behaviour. On an x86-64, copies will be fine and preserve all the bits, and this program will still be well formed. On a platform with extra pointer safety instructions, this might mangle the pointer value (or segfault or something). This is still implementation defined behaviour.

So your program is either ill-formed at compile time (because the `bit_cast` fails to compile) or implementation defined. There is no outright undefined behaviour.

Comment: A bigger issue if `std::list<T>::iterator` is implemented with an internal pointer would be that in the second bit_cast, there are going to be multiple pointer values with the same object representation. It could be pointing to the original object, or any other object at the same address or be an invalid pointer value. Practically I think it could interfere with pointer provenance assumptions for the optimizer when the pointer is later used.